# Asymptotes of algebraic curve

Tags: calculus

I read a remark in my calculus book that, asymptotes of a curve of n degree intersect the curve at n-2 points. I read the proof of this remark as well.can someone provide a geometric view of this statement. For xy =1 the x- axis and y-axis are the asymptotes and as degree is 2 so there is no point of intersection . Provide more example with some intersection points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^4-x^3 y-4 x^2 y^2+x^2 y+4 x y^3-9 y^3-11=0$

is a $4$th degree algebraic curve it has $4$ asymptotes.

[image]